# Can't Pass Json Data to MVC View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to pass Json data to a html table inside my view. For whatever reason I can not get it to work. Here's my code. I have a "group codes" sidebar and the table should be filtering based on the selected group code. When I "alert(data)" I get the data I need only if i serialize like below or else I just get [objet] [Object]. Also if I do $('.xx').html(data) it returns data but in json format and obviously not in a tabled structure

```
--Controller 

[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(string grpCode)
    {  
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var data = serializer.Serialize(new EmployeeDAL().EmployeeData(grpCode).employeeList);    
         return Json(data);        
    }
--View

 $('#tbl tr td').click(function () {
            var selection = $(this).text().trim();

            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Home/Index/",
                dataType: "Json",
                data: { grpCode: selection },                    
                success: function (data) {                      
                    alert(data);
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        var row = $("<tr />");
                        $("<td />").text(item.First_Name).appendTo(row);
                           $("<td />").text(item.Last_Name).appendTo(row);
                           $("<td />").text(item.Work_Pager).appendTo(row);
                           $("<td />").text(item.Effective_Date).appendTo(row);                           
                        row.appendTo("table.xx");
                    });
<table class="xx">  </table>

--Sample JSon [{"Last_Name": "Brown",
    "First_Name": "Rodney" "Work_Pager": "43343"}]
```

I'm just using that "junk" table for testing purposes. When I get it to work the real table will be structured normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonResult automatically serializes your object to JSON.
You should use:

```
public JsonResult Index(string grpCode)
{  
    var data = new EmployeeDAL().EmployeeData(grpCode).employeeList;    
     return Json(data);        
}
```

Edit:
If alerting data gives you  `[object] [Oject]` then what is returned isn't probably a simple list of items but a complex object.

For Example:

```
{"items":[{"name":"test","completed":false},{"name":"test2","completed":true}]}
```

then the array of items (test and test2) would be contained in data.items, and you could get the length of the array by using: `alert(data.items.length);`

For debugging I reccomend using Chrome and specifically using the Network and Sources-tabs.

Comment: thats what I was using but then my alert(data) would return [object] [Oject] so I serialized to be able to view the result in an alert

Comment: That is the default return value of an objects `toString` method. To get it to say something different you will have to overwrite it. I would recommend using `console.log(data)` for debugging instead of alert

Comment: If you want to use alerts you can use `JSON.stringify` ex: `alert(JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: ok thats good to know, this was such a rookie mistake i deserialized it and things started working. I did that because things weren't working then I changed it around and you know how that goes. Thank you